# Image upload when exists 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php

I am making image uploader and It works fine until I tryed to upload image with same name. I did recursive method in class, maybe that is problem.
I got this error:

> 500 Internal Server Error

Image is not big, and it works when does not exists.

Here is my upload.php file:

```
$upload = new Upload("post", $_FILES['file']);
$upload->upload();
```

And here is my Uploader.php class file:

```
class Upload {

protected $_type = null,
          $_file = null,
          $_file_name = null,
          $_file_tmp = null,
          $_slug = null,
          $_path = null;

public function __construct($type, $file, $slug = null) {
    $this->_file = $file;
    $this->_file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $this->_file_name = $file['name'];
    $this->_slug = $slug;

    if($type == "post") {
        $this->_type = "post";
        $config1 = '/admin/posts/images'; // Relative to domain name
        $config = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config1; // Physical path. [Usually works fine like this]
        $this->_path = $config . "/";
    } else if($type == "gallery") {
        $this->_type = "gallery";
        $config1 = '/admin/galeries/images'; // Relative to domain name
        $config = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config1; // Physical path. [Usually works fine like this]
        $this->_path = $config . "/";
    }
}

public function upload() {
    $new_name = "";
    if($this->_slug == null) {
        $new_name = $this->_file_name;
    } else {
        $new_name = $this->_slug . "-" . $this->_file_name;
    }

    if (file_exists($this->_path.$new_name)) {
        if($this->_slug != null)
            $new_name = $this->_slug . "-" . rand(00,99) . "-" . $this->_file_name;
        else
            $new_name = rand(0000,9999) . "-" . $new_name;

        // MAYBE HERE IS PROBLEM...
        $this->upload();
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($this->_file_tmp, $this->_path.$new_name);
        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can see my method upload() is called recursively. I am wondering if these protected variables are gone after that call.

Comment: How should `upload` be aware to the change you've done with `$new_name`? Or use it as a class property or pass it as a parameter, otherwise - it's out of the scope.

Comment: I would try to pass it as parameter

Comment: Btw all works when image does not exists

Comment: If it doesn't exist, the condition return false and your script runs the `else` part. The problem is in your `if` block - which seems to create an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `$this->_file_name = $new_name;` above `$this->upload();`

Comment: This is complete answer, I will check it like answer